Why do we need $g'(x) \neq 0$ in Hôpital Theorem?
I have searched all around here, and out of here, and I didn't find a single valid answer, not actually questions where this was asked. Is it possible that people just take things for granted?
In Hôpital Theorem, the first hypothesis requires that given $f, g$ differentiable function over $(a, b)$ where $a, b, \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ is that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \in (a, b)$.

Why??

I cannot understand the reason for this.
On Wikipedia the explanation is rather stupid: it just shows a counterexample without saying any reason.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#3._Derivative_of_denominator_is_zero
Thank you!

It's not clear what you'd consider a valid answer.  The condition is there because if it is omitted, the statement is not true (as shown by the counterexample).

@RobertIsrael That counterexample is not trivial, and before one finds something like that one need to really reason on why a counterexample could exist. Hence on the condition... Saying that a counterexample shows the condition is necessary doesn't answer to WHY it is necessary, and this is what I am looking for

One counter-example is all you need to show that the condition is needed. A theorem gives the conditions under which a conclusion can always be drawn. The confusion is in calling it L'hospital's rule. Rules, unlike laws or theorems, have exceptions.

@JohnDouma Yes but you don't wake up in the morning with a counterexample. There might take years to arrive at one. So before it, you cannot see the necessity of a certain condition

@Heidegger Are you suggesting that they should have left the condition out and gave you time to digest the theorem before revealing the counter-example?

@JohnDouma Of course no. What I mean is: in the exact moment you post a necessary condition, you should clearly explain why you need it and then provide a counterexample, not the other way round. You can provide a counterexample but you cannot say "we need it otherwise here, a counterexample that explains why we need it".

@Heidegger The counter-example provides the reason the condition is needed. If we remove the condition on the derivative of the denominator, the counter-example shows that the theorem is no longer true. It is certainly valid to question why conditions are needed for theorems to be true, but it is not valid to call a counter-example a stupid reason. Wouldn't it be worse to provide a reason with no counter-example?

Without this condition, the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f'(x)/g'(x)$ need not exist.
Consider what happens if $f'$ is never zero on the interval, but $g'$ is zero with an accumulation point of zeroes at $x = c$.  (If the set of accumulation points of zeroes of $g'$ does not include $c$, then we can take a smaller interval on which $g'$ is never zero.)  Then the ratio $f'/g'$ is undefined infinitely often and the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f'(x)/g'(x)$ does not exist.
We can also allow $f'$ to be zero on the interval and this can result in $f'(c) = 0$, $g'(c) = 0$, there is an interval $I_2$, on which $g''(x)$ is nonzero and the limit $f''/g''$ exists.  I.e., there is a chance that the original limit exists if the "apply the theorem twice" limit exists.
